# Cropping image in PHP

Tags: php, gd, image, crop

I'd like crop an image in PHP and save the file. I know your supposed to use the GD library but i'm not sure how. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: If you would like to [crop with configurable alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49851547/1494454), check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49851547/1494454).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could use `imagecopy` to crop a required part of an image. The command goes like this:

```
imagecopy  ( 
    resource $dst_im - the image object ,
    resource $src_im - destination image ,
    int $dst_x - x coordinate in the destination image (use 0) , 
    int $dst_y - y coordinate in the destination image (use 0) , 
    int $src_x - x coordinate in the source image you want to crop , 
    int $src_y - y coordinate in the source image you want to crop , 
    int $src_w - crop width ,
    int $src_h - crop height 
)
```

Code from [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php) - a 80x40 px image is cropped from a source image

```
<?php
// Create image instances
$src = imagecreatefromgif('php.gif');
$dest = imagecreatetruecolor(80, 40);

// Copy
imagecopy($dest, $src, 0, 0, 20, 13, 80, 40);

// Output and free from memory
header('Content-Type: image/gif');
imagegif($dest);

imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($src);
?>
```

Comment: Wont this method add black background to PNG images? I mean over the transparent background?

Comment: You could also use [`imagecrop`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecrop.php).

Answer (score 3):

This function will crop image maintaining image aspect ratio :)

```
 function resize_image_crop($image, $width, $height)
     {

        $w = @imagesx($image); //current width

        $h = @imagesy($image); //current height
        if ((!$w) || (!$h)) { $GLOBALS['errors'][] = 'Image couldn\'t be resized because it wasn\'t a valid image.'; return false; }
        if (($w == $width) && ($h == $height)) { return $image; }  //no resizing needed
        $ratio = $width / $w;       //try max width first...
        $new_w = $width;
        $new_h = $h * $ratio;    
        if ($new_h < $height) {  //if that created an image smaller than what we wanted, try the other way
            $ratio = $height / $h;
            $new_h = $height;
            $new_w = $w * $ratio;
        }
        $image2 = imagecreatetruecolor ($new_w, $new_h);
        imagecopyresampled($image2,$image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_w, $new_h, $w, $h);    
        if (($new_h != $height) || ($new_w != $width)) {    //check to see if cropping needs to happen
            $image3 = imagecreatetruecolor ($width, $height);
            if ($new_h > $height) { //crop vertically
                $extra = $new_h - $height;
                $x = 0; //source x
                $y = round($extra / 2); //source y
                imagecopyresampled($image3,$image2, 0, 0, $x, $y, $width, $height, $width, $height);
            } else {
                $extra = $new_w - $width;
                $x = round($extra / 2); //source x
                $y = 0; //source y
                imagecopyresampled($image3,$image2, 0, 0, $x, $y, $width, $height, $width, $height);
            }
            imagedestroy($image2);
            return $image3;
        } else {
            return $image2;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't need to do multiple imagecopyresampled calls, it can all be done on one call if the offset is calculated in to the $width and $height. Also, might be preferable to always force the resize to ensure that the image is saved in a new format stripped of additional garbage and headers and forced to a specific quality.

Answer (score 1):

To crop an image using GD you need to use a combination of GD methods, and if you look at "Example #1" on PHP's documentation of the `imagecopyresampled` method, it shows you how to crop and output an image, you would just need to add some code to that to capture and write the output to a file...

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php

There are also other options, including [Image Magick](http://www.imagemagick.org) which, if installed on your server, can be accessed directly using PHP's `exec` method (or similar) or you can install the PHP [Imagick](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.imagick.php) extension, which yields higher quality images and, in my opinion, is a little more intuitive and flexible to work with.

Finally, I've used the open source [PHPThumb](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/) class library, which has a pretty simple interface and can work with multiple options depending on what's on your server, including ImageMagick and GD.

Answer (score 0):

I use this script in some projects and it's pretty easy to use:
http://shiftingpixel.com/2008/03/03/smart-image-resizer/

The script requires PHP 5.1.0 (which is out since 2005-11-24 - time to upgrade if not yet at this version) and GD (which is rarely missing from good Web hosts).

Here is an example of it's use in your HTML:

```
<img src="/image.php/coffee-bean.jpg?width=200&amp;height=200&amp;image=/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/coffee-bean.jpg" alt="Coffee Bean" />
```

Comment: shiftingpixel.com seems down for the moment try the link later :)

Comment: shiftingpixel.com is back now :)

Answer (score 0):

I just created this function and it works for my needs, creating a centered and cropped thumbnail image. It is streamlined and doesn't require multiple imagecopy calls like shown in webGautam's answer.

Provide the image path, the final width and height, and optionally the quality of the image. I made this for creating thumbnails, so all images are saved as JPGs, you can edit it to accommodate other image types if you require them. The main point here is the math and method of using imagecopyresampled to produce a thumbnail. Images are saved using the same name, plus the image size.

```
function resize_crop_image($image_path, $end_width, $end_height, $quality = '') {
 if ($end_width < 1) $end_width = 100;
 if ($end_height < 1) $end_height = 100;
 if ($quality < 1 || $quality > 100) $quality = 60;

 $image = false;
 $dot = strrpos($image_path,'.');
 $file = substr($image_path,0,$dot).'-'.$end_width.'x'.$end_height.'.jpg';
 $ext = substr($image_path,$dot+1);

 if ($ext == 'jpg' || $ext == 'jpeg') $image = @imagecreatefromjpeg($image_path);
 elseif($ext == 'gif') $image = @imagecreatefromgif($image_path);
 elseif($ext == 'png') $image = @imagecreatefrompng($image_path);

 if ($image) {
  $width = imagesx($image);
  $height = imagesy($image);
  $scale = max($end_width/$width, $end_height/$height);
  $new_width = floor($scale*$width);
  $new_height = floor($scale*$height);
  $x = ($new_width != $end_width ? ($width - $end_width) / 2 : 0);
  $y = ($new_height != $end_height ? ($height - $end_height) / 2 : 0);
  $new_image = @imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);

  imagecopyresampled($new_image,$image,0,0,$x,$y,$new_width,$new_height,$width - $x,$height - $y);
  imagedestroy($image);
  imagejpeg($new_image,$file,$quality);
  imagedestroy($new_image);

  return $file;
 }
 return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use below method to crop image,

```
/*parameters are 
    $image =source image name
    $width = target width
    $height = height of image
    $scale = scale of image*/
    function resizeImage($image,$width,$height,$scale) {
        //generate new image height and width of source image
        $newImageWidth = ceil($width * $scale);
        $newImageHeight = ceil($height * $scale);
        //Create a new true color image
        $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newImageWidth,$newImageHeight);
        //Create a new image from file 
        $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
        //Copy and resize part of an image with resampling
        imagecopyresampled($newImage,$source,0,0,0,0,$newImageWidth,$newImageHeight,$width,$height);
        //Output image to file
        imagejpeg($newImage,$image,90);
        //set rights on image file
        chmod($image, 0777);
        //return crop image
        return $image;
    }
```

Comment: It might be helpful to users if you add comments to your code to explain what key parts do. This would help them better understand and apply your code