# Crop Image From Center PHP

Tags: php, image-processing

I want to crop an image from the center in the size 200 * 130 the image to be cropped may vary in size, if the image is smaller we wont crop it i know how to this part where  i can check height and with of image but kind of struck into the thing of cropping from the middle of the image
As i cant figure it out how to keep the center as crop point and than outward crop it

Answer (score 36, accepted):

GD comes bundled with all PHP installations from version 4.3.6 onwards so chances are, you have it.

Here's the steps you need to take...

1. Create an image resource using one of the GD [`imagecreatefrom*()`](http://php.net/manual/ref.image.php) functions. The one you use depends on the type of image you're dealing with
2. Determine the image dimensions using [`imagesx()`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.imagesx.php) and [`imagesy()`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.imagesy.php)
3. Determine your crop coordinates using the following algorithm and crop using [`imagecopy()`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.imagecopy.php)

Find crop coordinates

```
$width  = imagesx($img);
$height = imagesy($img);
$centreX = round($width / 2);
$centreY = round($height / 2);

$cropWidth  = 200;
$cropHeight = 130;
$cropWidthHalf  = round($cropWidth / 2); // could hard-code this but I'm keeping it flexible
$cropHeightHalf = round($cropHeight / 2);

$x1 = max(0, $centreX - $cropWidthHalf);
$y1 = max(0, $centreY - $cropHeightHalf);

$x2 = min($width, $centreX + $cropWidthHalf);
$y2 = min($height, $centreY + $cropHeightHalf);
```

Somebody implemented a handy class that encapsulates this logic here ~ [ImageManipulator.php](https://github.com/hungtrieu/html5-image-upload/blob/master/ImageManipulator.php)

Comment: In the first algorithm, which variables would correspond to the correct parameters of imagecopy() ?

Comment: Hi @Phil the Gist links do not work anymore, 8 years later. Any change you still have this library?

Comment: @EugenevanderMerwe you're in luck, somebody cloned it ~ https://github.com/hungtrieu/html5-image-upload/blob/master/ImageManipulator.php

Answer (score 20):

### Image crop with configurable alignment

Here is a native implementation of a function (called `cropAlign`) that **can crop an image to a given width and height with align** to the 9 standard points (4 edges, 4 corners, 1 center).

[image: Alignment points]

Just pass the image, the desired size of the crop, and the alignment on the two axis (you can use `left`, `center`, `right` or `top`, `middle`, `bottom` irregardless from the axis) for the `cropAlign` function.

### Specification

> #### Description
>
> ```
> cropAlign(resource $image, int $width, int $height, string $horizontalAlign = 'center', string $verticalAlign = 'middle')
> ```
>
> #### Parameters
>
> - **`image`**: An image resource, returned by one of the image creation functions, such as [`imagecreatetruecolor()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php).
> - **`width`**: Width of the final cropped image.
> - **`height`**: Height of the final cropped image.
> - **`horizontalAlign`**: Where the crop should be aligned along the horizontal axis. Possible values are: `left`/`top`, `center`/`middle`, `right`/`bottom`.
> - **`verticalAlign`**: Where the crop should be aligned along the vertical axis. Possible values are: `left`/`top`, `center`/`middle`, `right`/`bottom`.
>
> #### Return Values
>
> Return cropped image resource on success or `FALSE` on failure. This comes from [`imagecrop()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecrop.php).

### Source code

```php
function cropAlign($image, $cropWidth, $cropHeight, $horizontalAlign = 'center', $verticalAlign = 'middle') {
    $width = imagesx($image);
    $height = imagesy($image);
    $horizontalAlignPixels = calculatePixelsForAlign($width, $cropWidth, $horizontalAlign);
    $verticalAlignPixels = calculatePixelsForAlign($height, $cropHeight, $verticalAlign);
    return imageCrop($image, [
        'x' => $horizontalAlignPixels[0],
        'y' => $verticalAlignPixels[0],
        'width' => $horizontalAlignPixels[1],
        'height' => $verticalAlignPixels[1]
    ]);
}

function calculatePixelsForAlign($imageSize, $cropSize, $align) {
    switch ($align) {
        case 'left':
        case 'top':
            return [0, min($cropSize, $imageSize)];
        case 'right':
        case 'bottom':
            return [max(0, $imageSize - $cropSize), min($cropSize, $imageSize)];
        case 'center':
        case 'middle':
            return [
                max(0, floor(($imageSize / 2) - ($cropSize / 2))),
                min($cropSize, $imageSize),
            ];
        default: return [0, $imageSize];
    }
}
```

### Example usage

Here are some crop examples using [this image](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Utah_teapot_simple_2.png) of the [Utah teapot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utah_teapot).

```php
$im = imagecreatefrompng('https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJcML.png');
imagePng(cropAlign($im, 200, 250, 'center', 'middle'));
imagePng(cropAlign($im, 300, 150, 'left', 'top'));
imagePng(cropAlign($im, 1000, 250, 'right', 'middle'));
```

#### Input

[image: Example input: Utah teapot]

#### Output

```
cropAlign($im, 200, 250, 'center', 'middle')
```

[image: Output #1]

```
cropAlign($im, 300, 150, 'left', 'top')
```

[image: Output #2]

```
cropAlign($im, 1000, 250, 'right', 'middle')
```

[image: Output #3]

Comment: Really great, it's more useful

Answer (score 2):

Jeez, why are you doing it the hard way? Just simply set the x and y positions as the amount to crop / 2

```
   $imageSize = getimagesize('thumbnail.png');

$croppedImage = imagecrop(imagecreatefrompng('thumbnail.png'), ['x' => 0, 'y' => ($imageSize[1]-$imageSize[0]*(9/16))/2, 'width' => $imageSize[0], 'height' =>  $imageSize[0]*(9/16)]);
```

notice how I used my $imageSize[0]*(9/16), which is the amount i am cropping by in the y direction, and i subtracted that from the original image height to find crop amount, then divided by 2. If you want to do the same for width, simply follow the same steps.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

```
function cropCentered($img, $w, $h)
{
  $cx = $img->getWidth() / 2;
  $cy = $img->getHeight() / 2;
  $x = $cx - $w / 2;
  $y = $cy - $h / 2;
  if ($x < 0) $x = 0;
  if ($y < 0) $y = 0;
  return $img->crop($x, $y, $w, $h);
}
```

I'm assuming you're using the GD library. $img is a GD image, $w and $h are width and height, respectively, you want your new  image to have. In your case, $w = 200, $h = 130.

Comment: No I donot have GD library available with me

Comment: @June GD is included in most php installations, use `phpinfo()` and you most likely see it

Comment: Can you help me in creating above with NO GD Library and saving the image?

Comment: As am not aware of Gd Library i got this error 
Fatal error: Call to a member function getWidth() on a non-object in /home/content/12/7942812/html/contest/GdPHPCrop.php on line 4
so i want to keep away from GD

Comment: What is a "GD image"? All GD creation functions return a resource identifier. AFAIK, there is no object oriented GD interface out of the box

Comment: You're right Phil. Actually I'm used to use a wrapper class for this kind of manipulation of images. As I answered the question I assumed the guy had more knowledge about manipulating images.

Comment: I'm confused, there is no crop function built into the GD library... So is this answer a piggy back off of the original answer? If so then you should mention that, otherwise this answer is totally incorrect as the user doesn't know the context you're speaking in.