# crop image from center without GD library and generate a thumbnail

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Crop Image From Center PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891352/crop-image-from-center-php)

I need to crop an image from the center with size of  200 * 130 using PHP. Any help will be hugely be appreciated.

Comment: Why "without GD"? Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't agree this is duplicate, since he specifies in the question that is a solution not using GD. You may have to use a web host where you can't change PHP to install GD, so in this case you need another solution.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to crop an image using PHP without any libraries. There are a lot of built-in solutions. Take a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.image.php

Comment: This involves a lot of coding, but it is possible.

Comment: @RedDragon Parsing image format in PHP? That's extreme programming, I think)

Comment: Indeed, but not impossible...

Comment: Yes, I had to use other words, I agree with you