# Image resizing without deformation

Tags: php, gd

I'm trying to create a thumbnail with gd library, but my thumbnail is always distorted. What I want is to cut the image starting from the center respecting a new resolution and losing the old proportion.

What I've tried:

```
$im = ImageCreateFromJPEG($target_file);
$n_width = 500; // Fix the width of the thumb nail images
$n_height = 500; // Fix the height of the thumb nail imaage
$width = ImageSx($im); // Original picture width is stored
$height = ImageSy($im); // Original picture height is stored
$newimage = imagecreatetruecolor($n_width, $n_height);
imagecopyresampled($newimage, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $n_width, $n_height, $width, $height);
$thumb_target = $target_dir . $filename_without_ext . '-thumb.' . $params['file_ext'];
ImageJpeg($newimage, $thumb_target);
chmod("$thumb_target", 0777);
```

Tried to change `imagecreatetruecolor` to `imagecrop` but still not with the behavior that I want.

Please let me know if I was not clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it using [ImageManipulator](https://gist.github.com/philBrown/880506) library. Found the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6894390/2767026).

My final code:

```
$im = new ImageManipulator($target_file);
$centreX = round($im->getWidth() / 2);
$centreY = round($im->getHeight() / 2);

$x1 = $centreX - 500;
$y1 = $centreY - 500;

$x2 = $centreX + 500;
$y2 = $centreY + 500;

$im->crop($x1, $y1, $x2, $y2);
$im->save($target_dir . $filename_without_ext . '-thumb.' . $params['file_ext']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your new dimensions produce a square; this will always distort the thumbnail unless the original image was (very nearly) square.  If you calculate the new dimensions from the old (find the larger dimension, divide by 500 pixel, multiply the smaller by same ratio), you'll get a non-square thumbnail with the same proportion, hence it won't look distorted.

If you *need* the thumbs to be square, you could convert the smaller dimension to 500 pixels, create the image as I've suggested above, then crop to 500x500.

Comment: I need a square thumbnail but my original imagem isn't square.

Comment: @WilliamWeckl There is no magic. You can crop, or use css background position(but you can't redimension it this way), or just edit this image. It will always distort. If you can't cut it, you can create an image with 500px width, height proportional, inside a `div`(or anything you like), centralize it, and add some background matching your likes.

Comment: @klauskpm I wanna crop it, just don't know exactly how with this gd commands.