Deprecated: Implicit conversion from float xxx.x to int loses precision
First, my apologies if this is a stupid question. I haven't written much (if any) PHP in several years, so i'm beyond rusty (at best).
I have this script which takes an image and adds text to it. It used to work but apparently in the latest version of PHP which my webhost is using it breaks, throwing the error "The image “http://localhost/old1.php” cannot be displayed because it contains errors."
To analyse why, i changed the header Content-Type to text/plain. It throws the error "Deprecated:  Implicit conversion from float xxx.x to int loses precision" on several lines (36-41) toward the end of the script (some - but not all - of the lines starting with imagettftext). This is the part i fail to understand. I should add that i am a profoundly un-clever person whose brain has been extremely foggy since covid, so it's difficult for me to trace back what actual numbers are being spit out as floats and where they're breaking because of not being integers, because frankly i just don't remember how my own script works.
<?php
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
//Report any errors
/*
ini_set("display_errors", "1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
*/
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

$tomorrow = new DateTime('tomorrow');

$name = "my dead name";
$text = "16 Jul 1978 - ".$tomorrow->format('j M Y');
$text2 = "RIP you POS";
$text3 = "good riddance                   stupid bastard";
$im     = imagecreatefromjpeg("old1.jpg");
$font = "trebucbd.ttf";
$font2 = "trebuc.ttf";
$color = imagecolorallocate($im, 120, 180, 255);
$color2 = imagecolorallocate($im, 180, 10, 0);
$color3 = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$color4 = imagecolorallocate($im, 120, 0, 0);
$shadow = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$size = 30;
$bbox = imagettfbbox($size, 0, $font, $text);
$bbox2 = imagettfbbox($size, 0, $font, $text2);
$bbox3 = imagettfbbox($size, 0, $font2, $name);
$px = $bbox[0] + (imagesx($im) / 2) - ($bbox[4] / 2) - strlen($text);
$px2 = $bbox2[0] + (imagesx($im) / 2) - ($bbox2[4] / 2) - strlen($text2);
$px3 = $bbox3[0] + (imagesx($im) / 2) - ($bbox3[4] / 2) - strlen($name);
//$px     = (imagesx($im) - 7.5 * strlen($text)) / 2;
$py = 500;
//imagestring($im, 10, $px, 500, $string, $color);
imagettftext($im, $size, 0, $px3+2, 82, $shadow, $font2, $name);
imagettftext($im, $size, 0, $px3, 80, $color3, $font2, $name);
imagettftext($im, $size*1.2, 0, $px-18, $py+2, $shadow, $font, $text);
imagettftext($im, $size*1.2, 0, $px-20, $py, $color, $font, $text);
imagettftext($im, $size, 0, $px2+22, $py+62, $shadow, $font, $text2);
imagettftext($im, $size, 0, $px2+20, $py+60, $color2, $font, $text2);
imagettftext($im, $size*.5, 0, $px2-68, $py+92, $shadow, $font, $text3);
imagettftext($im, $size*.5, 0, $px2-70, $py+90, $color4, $font, $text3);
imagejpeg($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>

To be totally honest, i just don't know where to start trying to fix this, since none of the functions i've looked at appear to be incompatible with PHP 8.3.x. However, i had my webhost roll back PHP to 8.0 and the script works. I've looked at this question and still can't seem to figure out where the actual problem is. My goal is to reformulate whatever i need to so i can use the latest version of PHP going forward. Thank you very sincerely for any suggestions.
EDIT: solved thanks to @phil; here's the fixed bit:
'''
$px = $bbox[0] + (round(imagesx($im) / 2)) - (round($bbox[4] / 2)) - strlen($text);
$px2 = $bbox2[0] + (round(imagesx($im) / 2)) - (round($bbox2[4] / 2)) - strlen($text2);
$px3 = $bbox3[0] + (round(imagesx($im) / 2)) - (round($bbox3[4] / 2)) - strlen($name);
//$px     = (imagesx($im) - 7.5 * strlen($text)) / 2;
'''

You're passing some float numbers to functions that expect integers. Namely $px, $px2 and $px3. They're floats because of your / 2 operations. You should round / floor / ceil / cast them to integers

Here's an example using round() ~ https://stackoverflow.com/a/6894390/283366

@Phil THANK YOU
Here's the edited bit:
'
$px = $bbox[0] + (round(imagesx($im) / 2)) - (round($bbox[4] / 2)) - strlen($text);
$px2 = $bbox2[0] + (round(imagesx($im) / 2)) - (round($bbox2[4] / 2)) - strlen($text2);
$px3 = $bbox3[0] + (round(imagesx($im) / 2)) - (round($bbox3[4] / 2)) - strlen($name);
//$px     = (imagesx($im) - 7.5 * strlen($text)) / 2;
'
it seems to work as expected now
