# how to crop a jpg image only with php?

Tags: php, image, jpeg, crop

using ImageMagic the cropping can be done easily with below code , but it's impossible to install ImageMagic in the hosting server.so is there any way to do this with only php? need to crop **jpg images** not png. and how to stop reducing the quality og the image?

```
$image = new Imagick($inFile);
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($inFile);
$image->cropImage($width,$height-60, -60,0);
$image->writeImage($outFile);
```

Comment: It's in `php`, easier ten you think: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecrop.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cropping image in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008911/cropping-image-in-php)

Comment: @ImamAssidiqqi that answer makes a black line after cropping :-/

Answer (score 0):

Here is some alternatives for cropping images:

Use composer package `intervention\image`:

https://packagist.org/packages/intervention/image

Use image manipulation as a service by cloudinary (it's powerful and free/cheap simple image manipulation and storage on cloud):

http://cloudinary.com