# How to crop 45px from the top and bottom of a jpeg

Tags: php

I am trying to crop off 45px from the top and bottom of YouTube jpeg thumbnail images, for example [this one](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/1yqVD0swvWU/hqdefault.jpg) which is 480px x 360px.

It looks like this:

[image]

Notice the 45px black bars on the top and bottom of the image. I simply want those removed such that my resulting image is 480px x 270px and the black bars are gone.

I have achieved partial success by implementing the example from [this stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008911/cropping-image-in-php). Here is my PHP function based on that:

```
function CropImage($sourceImagePath, $width, $height){
    $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($sourceImagePath);
    $dest = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    imagecopy($dest, $src, 0, 0, 20, 13, $width, $height);
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($dest);
    imagedestroy($dest);
    imagedestroy($src);
}
```

And called thusly:

```
CropImage("LOTR.jpg", 480, 270);
```

Some cropping occurs, but 2 problems result:

1. It doesn't crop the top and bottom, rather it seems to crop the left side and the bottom, resulting in this:

   [image]
2. From the PHP code snippet I'm using I can't see how to generate a new file. Rather, the PHP script I execute in the browser simply renders the morphed file in the browser. I don't want this to happen, I want to be able to pass a dest path into the function and have it create the new file (and not send anything to the client/browser) with the top 45px and bottom 45px removed. It's obvious that `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');` is part of the problem, but removing that still doesn't give me a destination file written to the server, methinks.

I'm also looking in the [PHP docs here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php). It seems like changing the params in `imagecopy($dest, $src, 0, 0, 20, 13, $width, $height);` would solve this, but it's really unclear to me what those params should be. The [resulting thumbnails inside the YouTube tab look odd](http://www.zingfilter.com/FilterList.php) with the black bars.

Comment: [imagecopy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php) [imagejpeg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php)

Comment: What do I pass to `imagejpeg()`? `$src`? `$dest`? Something else?

Comment: Both. You only need to change `$src_x` and `$src_y`, 20 and 13 are wrong.

Comment: And how does it write the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the code comments for an explanation:

```
<?php
function CropImage($sourceImagePath, $width, $height){

    // Figure out the size of the source image
    $imageSize = getimagesize($sourceImagePath);
    $imageWidth = $imageSize[0];
    $imageHeight = $imageSize[1];

    // If the source image is already smaller than the crop request, return (do nothing)
    if ($imageWidth < $width || $imageHeight < $height) return;

    // Get the adjustment by dividing the difference by two
    $adjustedWidth = ($imageWidth - $width) / 2;
    $adjustedHeight = ($imageHeight - $height) / 2;
   
    $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($sourceImagePath);

    // Create the new image
    $dest = imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);      

    // Copy, using the adjustment to crop the source image
    imagecopy($dest, $src, 0, 0, $adjustedWidth, $adjustedHeight, $width, $height);
    
    imagejpeg($dest,'somefile.jpg');
    imagedestroy($dest);
    imagedestroy($src);
}
```

Comment: user2182349 your solution works perfectly except I still don't see how to save the modified image to the server. `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');` certainly needs to be removed, but what is the syntax for saving the changed image?

Comment: Yes, that's it. Please update your answer with that, and `header` removed. So I can accept, and it may help others.